# How to subtract rows (lines) with AWK

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to figure out how I can use [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) to subtract lines. For example, imagine the input file is:

```
30
20
```

The output would be:

```
10
```

Now, as a test I am trying to calculate the "Used" memory column from:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
```

So at the moment I have written this:

```
$ grep -P 'MemTotal|MemFree' /proc/meminfo | \
    -- Here comes the calculation using AWK
```

I have tried the following:

```
$ grep -P 'MemTotal|MemFree' /proc/meminfo | \
    awk '{print $2}' | awk '{$0-s}{s=$0} END {print s}'
```

But this just gives me the last row of data.

I've found a working solution, but I doubt it's the most optimal one. All my coding experience tells me that hard coding the amount of rows is terrible :P

```
$ grep -P 'MemTotal|MemFree' /proc/meminfo | \
    awk '{print $2}' | awk 'NR == 1{s=$0} NR == 2 {s=s-$0} END {print s}'
```

Comment: What would you want done with N rows? Should the final result be  `line1_$2 - line2_$2 - lineN-$2`? Do you only want to subtract the first two consecutive rows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also do this using `awk`, `paste`, and `bc`. I find this approach easier to remember, the syntax of `awk` always requires me to look things up to confirm.

**NOTE:** This approach has the advantage of being able to contend with multiple lines of output, subtracting the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. numbers from the 1st.

```
$ grep -P 'MemTotal|MemFree' /proc/meminfo | \
    awk '{print $2}' | paste -sd- - | bc
7513404
```

#### Details

The above uses `awk` to select the column that contains the numbers we want to subtract.

```
$ grep -P 'MemTotal|MemFree' /proc/meminfo | \
    awk '{print $2}'
7969084
408432
```

We then use `paste` to combine these 2 values values and add the minus sign in between them.

```
$ grep -P 'MemTotal|MemFree' /proc/meminfo | \
    awk '{print $2}'| paste -sd- -
7969084-346660
```

When we pass this to `bc` it performs the calculation.

```
$ grep -P 'MemTotal|MemFree' /proc/meminfo | \
    awk '{print $2}'| paste -sd- - | bc
7513404
```

Comment: @terdon - thanks I was making that edit when you did it 8-)

Answer (score 6):

The purely awk solution, no redundant cat or grep commands:

`awk '/MemTotal/ {TOT=$2} /MemFree/ {FREE=$2} END {printf("%d kB Used\n", TOT-FREE)}' /proc/meminfo`

I see awk_FTW beat me to it but I though formatting the output could be nice.

Comment: Excellent! I love it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
grep -P 'MemTotal|MemFree' /proc/meminfo | \
awk 'NR==1{s=$2;next}{s-=$2}END{print s}'
```